# Postgresql: Does execute() or fetch() download result from remote?

Tags: postgresql, query, python, remote

When getting a query result from a remote server, does the execution of the query transmit the result to the local machine, or is it buffered on remote and only downloaded when fetching the result?

Here is how the cursor is defined:

```
con = psycopg2.connect(f"host='{host}' port='{port}' dbname='{DB}' user='{user}' password='{pw}'")

cur = con.cursor()
```

Comment: I am trying to separate the download speed from the query execution time to see which is more time-consuming...

Comment: With psycopg2, it depends on how the cursor is defined.  You should show the code.  The most common way, the execute retrieves all the results into local memory managed by C, and fetch just hands them over to python.

Comment: @jjanes, please verify after I added the code snippet if you can